# Hide password text on iPad

Tags: ipad

I've recently bought new iPad 3 and I'm new to use an iPad. I'm trying to find a way to set password asterisks by default while currently when I type password each character is display for 2-3 seconds. How can I set password at asterisks by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters are not displayed for 2-3 seconds if you keep typing. Typing a new character immediately masks the old one.

It is not possible to hide all typed characters behind asterisks at all times.

The solution? Just keep typing :). The last character you typed is there in case you're wondering if you made a mistake. But only for a few seconds.

Comment: May I know why & who has voted down question? As I've just posted my query about an iPad. If my colleague or any other person is just setting beside me and we're trying to log in to the application he can easily see the password. This is reasonable question then why voted down?

Comment: 1. You probably should have added that comment to the question, not my answer :). 2. It's really not a good idea to call out votes. Votes are anonymous and really should (mostly) remain that way. 3. Ask your colleague to turn away temporarily. Simple solution to a simple problem. Either that or merely twist your iPad and use it privately while you enter your password.

Comment: 1. I'm not trying to call out votes by my comment. I'm just saying that there are not any reason to vote down the question if its not proper as per you, you can notify me by comment to close the question.
2. I mentioned one reason out of fews just to give you simple example.
3.If I attach my iPad to a big screen to display something to the team and that time in some urgent cases if I've to login on Skype or any other application then the problem might be raised.

Comment: You can simply unplug your iPad or temporarily disable AirPlay mirroring if you need screen privacy. The latter being slightly more involved but if you need to do it, do it. We can back and forth this all day, the point is: shy of Jailbreaking perhaps, there is *NO WAY* to permanently hide typed characters.